# Manga about blacksmith/martial artist who uses a hammer to smith and attack

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's about a prodigy in smithing. He uses a heavy hammer (100kg, I think). He then joined some rich and famous sect and became the best blacksmith there. It's set in a kinda futuristic era.

Comment: This is a good start, but I'll bet you can tease some more details from your memory. Can you remember any names of people in the story? Where was it set -- Japan, China, Europe? Did he forge his own hammer, or acquire it somehow? Are there fantastic elements, or is the story realistic? What is futuristic about the story -- high technology, downfall of civilization, or something else? The more details, the better the chance that someone will remember this manga.

Comment: Maybe useful, https://forum.novelupdates.com/threads/blacksmith-mc.6194/

Comment: this is a manhwa or manhua or manga ? I know 2 manhua like that. One is in VMROPG game and the second about a boy in another world.

Answer (score 1):

The manga you are looking for is called soul land 3 or douluo dalu 3

Comment: Could you perhaps add in some excerpts from the manga that would show that it is indeed what the questioner is looking for?

Comment: Technically sould land 1,3 both have weapon as hammer but MC aren't blacksmith and there are no job called blacksmith.

Comment: @someoneuseless: Just noting that the webnovel, at least, of *Soul Land 3*, has the protagonist taking his Blacksmith Ranking Test and passing with flying colors.